# create part of bitmap as a new bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, draw

i have a problem and i don't know how to solve it. What i'm trying to do is, to create a Bitmap which is a part of another Bitmap.

I tried already this

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, (int)x, (int) y, (int)width, (int)height);
```

The width/height of the new bitmap is alright, but it's empty, every pixel is just transparent.

So i searched and found that i have to use canvas to draw the part again, because the return of createBitmap is a empty once. But i'm not sure since the call up here returns an immutable Bitmap, which Canvas doesn't like. I also not know which constructor i have to use with canvas.

Could someone help me?

Thanks and greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That one will create an INMUTABLE bitmap. Please, refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html and read about that method.

To create a mutable one, use `createBitmap(DisplayMetrics display, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)`. Pass in the widht and height of the part u wanna render in and the displayMetrics you get from `yourActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`.

To render the area you want in the newly created bitmap, yes, use the Canvas. There are lots of methods. You can use this one: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.RectF, android.graphics.Paint)

You pass in a rect with the source area and the destination area.